# Adding an image - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a code using 'array of objects' that showing employees with details. I want to upload their images also. So where do I need to keep images(their path) in my ReactApp or I can upload from laptop's hard drive directly. What will be the code to upload an image for every single employee.

Here is my code below:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
      names: [
        { name: "Deepak", age: 25, profile: "Developer" },
        { name: "Deepika", age: 24, profile: "Designer" },
        { name: "Deepinder", age: 22, profile: "Tester" }
      ],
      filteredData: [{}]
    };
  }

  render() {
    let terms = "";
    if (this.state.term) {
      terms = this.state.term.toLowerCase();
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label>Search Employee: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.term}
          id="searchEmp"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          onChange={(event) => {
            if (event.target.value.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
              alert("Please don\'t enter space.");
              this.setState({ term: "" });
              return;
            }
            this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <br />

        {this.state.names &&
          this.state.names
            .filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(terms))
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <div className="data-body">
                  <div>Name = {item.name}</div>
                  <div>Job Profile = {item.job_profile}</div>
                  <div>Description = {item.description}</div>
                  <input type="button" id="button" value="Delete"/>
                  <div>{<br></br>}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `handleDelete` function to remove the user and update the state when the delete button is clicked.

```js
handleDelete = (name) => {
  const { names: users } = this.state
  this.setState({
    names: users.filter((user) => user.name !== name),
  })
}
```

You can now pass an `onClick` prop to the input button to call the `handleDelete` function passing the name of the selected user.

```
<input
  type="button"
  id="button"
  value="Delete"
  onClick={() => this.handleDelete(item.name)}
/>
```

The function uses the user's name to delete which won't always work since names aren't unique. Ideally, you want to use a unique id to identify users.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Stewart',
    job_profile: 'iOS Developer',
    description: 'He is an iOS Developer',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Andy',
    job_profile: 'React Developer',
    description: 'He is a React Developer',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Alex',
    job_profile: 'Android Developer',
    description: 'He is an Android Developer',
  },
]
```

Now that we have the id added to the users array, we can update the `handleDelete` function to use it to delete the selected user.

```js
handleDelete = (id) => {
  const { names: users } = this.state
  this.setState({
    names: users.filter((user) => user.id !== id),
  })
}
```

```
<input
  type="button"
  id="button"
  value="Delete"
  onClick={() => this.handleDelete(item.id)}
/>
```

---

Whenever you're rendering a list of items, it's important to add a [unique `key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to the items.

```
{
  names
    .filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(terms))
    .map((item) => {
      return (
        <div className="data-body" key={item.id}>
          ...
        </div>
      )
    })
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wozniak-yjlvl?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve that by this way :

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Delete" onClick={() => {
this.setState({ names: this.state.names.filter(i => i.name !== item.name) });
}}/>
```

Comment: Not the best way, becouse it will delete all employees with the same name

Comment: Yes, he/she should put "unique id" in the array.

Comment: @behzadSoleimani-i understand that there is need to make every employee unique. Apart what I want to say is that deletion of employee from screen is working fine with what you suggested but that deleted employee is still existing in 'array of objects' in my code. I want to delete his record from there also when deleted. is this possible? I hope I'm clear with my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice() method to remove specific user from array.

[code Sandbox Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-platform-9841z?file=/src/App.js)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
      names: [
        {
          name: "Stewart",
          job_profile: "iOS Developer",
          description: "He is an iOS Developer"
        },
        {
          name: "Andy",
          job_profile: "React Developer",
          description: "He is a React Developer"
        },
        {
          name: "Alex",
          job_profile: "Android Developer",
          description: "He is an Android Developer"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.names &&
          this.state.names.map((user, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <p>Name = {user.name}</p>
              <p>Job Profile = {user.job_profile}</p>
              <p>Description = {user.description}</p>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  const copyArr = [...this.state.names];
                  copyArr.splice(index, 1);
                  this.setState({ names: copyArr });
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```